# Error after adding horizontal lines in xyplot created via for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, error-handling

I am trying to add two different horizontal lines to  a xyplot(). Since It is a series of plot then I am using for loop:

```
vector = c(0.06, 0.98) 

for (x in vector){
  for(i in names((df1[,2:7]))){
  SetMethods::xy.plot(x = i, y ='rec', 
          data = as.data.frame(df1),
          necessity = TRUE,
          jitter = TRUE, 
          panel = function( x,y,...) {
            panel.abline( h= y[ which(x %in% vector) ], lty = "dotted", col = "black")
            panel.xyplot( x,y,...)
          })}}
```

Unfortunately I ma having as a result this error:

```
Error in if (dots$rob == TRUE) { : argument is of length zero
```

Anyone could have any idea of how to solve it?
Thanks

Here the dataset

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:6, Vid = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), Mus = c(1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1), Rea = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), Ema = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0), SMS = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), tel = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), 
    rec = c(1, 0.16, 0.99, 0.95, 0.98, 0.92), MMT = c(53, 17.5, 
    48.5, 40, 46, 38), MM_levels = c("HMM", "IMM", "HMM", "IMM", 
    "HMM", "IMM")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(c(`12` = 12L, `15` = 15L, 
`23` = 23L, `39` = 39L, `47` = 47L, `61` = 61L), class = "omit"))
```

Comment: Where is the function `xy.plot` from? Did you mean `lattice::xyplot` without the period?

Comment: That it is in SetMethods package. I do not know if it is possible to modify that kind plots. It is for qualitative comparison analysis

Comment: Possibly if I can give a suggestion, you could how to add horizontal lines through abline() function..of course reiterated

Comment: I seeing that it is not possible even outside the loop.. maybe could there be another method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xy.plot` method uses `ggplot2` under the good. If you want to add those lines you can add an additional `geom_line`. No need for a loop over the line values.

```
for(i in names((df1[,2:7]))){
  print(xy.plot(x = i, y ='rec', 
          data = as.data.frame(df1),
          necessity = TRUE,
          jitter = TRUE) + 
          geom_hline(yintercept=vector, linetype="dotted"))
}
```

[image]